# Having trouble with installing Wagtail for Python. Getting error of invalid syntax

Tags: python, wagtail

I'm having trouble installing Wagtail on my computer (Windows 10). I installed PyCharm, a Python IDE. According to the [wagtail website](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/getting_started/tutorial.html), I just need to run the following code to install Wagtail:
    $ pip install wagtail

However, I am getting the following error:

[image]

I have tried with and without the $ sign, but both don't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much!

Comment: `pip install wagtail` is a shell/cmd command, not a python statement.

Comment: I tried running in the python console and in the Windows Command Prompt but neither option worked either...

Comment: I'd recommend a few things for developing on Windows. First, get `git-bash` from here: https://git-for-windows.github.io/ Then, as mentioned below, learn what `virtualenvs` are and how to use them; they will save you a lot of headaches in the future and properly isolate your web sites required packages. There's a handy packaged, `virtualenvwrapper-win`, which you can `pip install` to manage your `virtualenvs`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is not wagtail-related.

First you need to install a proper python environment on your machine, preferably with virtualenv for isolated environments, for example have a look at http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-pip-virtualenv-installation-on-windows/.